# Using dual Y stepper drivers on Marlin / RAMPS 1.4

Tags: marlin, ramps-1.4, arduino-mega-2650

I am building a DIY 3D printer, and my hw requirements are X, Y1, Y2, Z, and E0 steppers. All of them are supposed to be A4988. One hotend heater, no heatbed (by now). My board is an Arduino Mega 2560, and I am trying to use the latest Marlin available (i.e. 2.1.2.2). The issue is that I can't get any movement on the Y2 motor. I have been crawling around, and what I think I should have  is as follows:

in Configuration.h,

```
#define MOTHERBOARD BOARD_RAMPS_14_EFF 
#define EXTRUDERS 1
#define Y2_DRIVER_TYPE A4988    //uncommented
```

in Configuration_adv.h

```
//#define Y_DUAL_STEPPER_DRIVERS
#if ENABLED(Y_DUAL_STEPPER_DRIVERS)
  #define INVERT_Y2_VS_Y_DIR true   // Set 'true' if Y motors should rotate in opposite directions
  //#define Y_DUAL_ENDSTOPS
  #if ENABLED(Y_DUAL_ENDSTOPS)
    #define Y2_USE_ENDSTOP _YMAX_
    #define Y_DUAL_ENDSTOPS_ADJUSTMENT  0
  #endif
#endif
```

Note: the `#define Y_DUAL_STEPPER_DRIVERS` statement **has** to be left commented otherwise a compilation error is raised.
This is the situation. Of course, I have tested the cables/motors, and all of them are working.
Other posts on different blogs drove me to tweak the  `pins_RAMPS.h` file, but I realized it was a waste of time.
Can you give me a hint? Otherwise, I will be forced to build an add-on nanocard hosting a couple of twin A4988 drivers, but the room on the RAMPS shield is so little. And I don't dare to drive two motors with a single A4988, I never tried but I know that A4988 are difficult guys.

Comment: No, you shouldn't (read *can't*) drive two motors with a single A4988. As an aside, this seems related to a (now deleted) question, [Can I add TMC stepsticks in parallel with existing A4988?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/q/23074/4762), which I had commented heavily upon. The same Q has now been asked on SE.Electronics, [Can I add TMC stepsticks in parallel with existing A4988?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/702418/64015). See meta Q, [Should I delete and repost in another community?](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/604/4762) for more background.

Comment: I might post my comments that are under the deleted question as an answer to this question, even though they aren't a solution, per se.

Comment: Thank you #Greenonline. I will not parallel motors, I am rather building an A4988 "twinner", unless some goodwilling fellow will show me how to use the available driver on top of the RAMPS shield.